# Import local JSON-file into HTML-table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON-file called data.json:

```
[{
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "EUVPulseCount",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "M",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "0",
    "id" : 0
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "EUVState",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "1",
    "id" : 1
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "Loop_Name",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "2",
    "id" : 2
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "Project_Info",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "3",
    "id" : 3
}
]
```

And I got this piece of HTMl-code which works right now, but I would like to have the headers added by code and not telling the script harcoded what the headers are. When this works, I can shorten my code and just use a for-loop and iterate trough the list of headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <script>
                $.getJSON('./data.json', function (data){
                html = ''
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        html += "<div class=\"row\"></div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Group-of-Signals name"] + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Group-of-Signals description"]  + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal name"]   + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal data type"]  + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal unit of measurement"]    + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal description"]    + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal ID"] + "</div>";
                        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value["Signal index"]  + "</div>";
                    });
                    html += "</div>";
                    $(".table").append(html);
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
With the code of millerf I managed to get the data but now I still have to declare the keys like this:

```
var headers = ["name", "description", "name", "data type", "unit of measurement", "description", "id", "index", "ID"]
$.getJSON('./data.json', function (data){
    html = ''
    for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
        html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + headers[i] + "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Be careful, Chrome along with some other browsers will not let you do ajax locally because of security concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another $.each, so you can have access to the header:

```
html = ''
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  html += "<div class=\"row\">";
  $.each(value, function(header, value2){
    html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value2+ "</div>";
  })
  html += "</div>"
});
html += "</div>";
$(".table").append(html);
```

Comment: See my UPDATE for a question

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your code like this:

```
$.getJSON('./data.json', function(data) {
    html = ''
    var headersPrinted = false;        
    var keys = [];
    for(var i in data) {
        if(headersPrinted == false) {                
            html += "<div class=\"header row\">";
            for(var name in data[i]) {
                html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + name + "</div>";
                keys.push(name);
            }
            html += "</div>"
            headersPrinted = true;
        }
        html += "<div class=\"row\"></div>";
        for(var key in keys){
            html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + data[i][keys[key]] + "</div>";
        }
    }        
    html += "</div>";
    $(".table").append(html);
});
```

Comment: tested and confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var html = "";
  var Myheader = ["Group-of-Signals name", "Group-of-Signals description", "Signal name", "Signal data type", "Signal unit of measurement",
    "Signal description", "Signal ID", "Signal index"
  ];
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    html += "<div class=\"row\"></div>";
    Myheader.forEach(function(key) {
      html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value[key] + "</div>";

    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.keys()` It is easy to do this kind of thing ;)

```js
var json = [{
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "EUVPulseCount",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "M",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "0",
    "id" : 0
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "EUVState",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "1",
    "id" : 1
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "Loop_Name",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "2",
    "id" : 2
}, {
    "Group-of-Signals name" : "DPI_0",
    "Group-of-Signals description" : "",
    "Signal name" : "Project_Info",
    "Signal data type" : "SDT_STRING",
    "Signal unit of measurement" : "",
    "Signal description" : "",
    "Signal ID" : "-1",
    "Signal index" : "3",
    "id" : 3
}
];

var html = '';

   $.each(json, function(key, value){
     if(key === 0) {
         html += "<div class=\"row\">";
         $.each(Object.keys(value), function(k, v) {
           html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + v + "</div>";
         });
         html += "</div>";
       }
     
     html += "<div class=\"row\">";
         $.each(Object.keys(value), function(k, v) {
           html += "<div class=\"cell\">" + value[v] + "</div>";
         });
         html += "</div>";

   });
console.log(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```